# How can I debug unit test in Visual Studio 2017 15.6.0

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

Brand new machine, new install of Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.6.0.
I cannot seem to debug tests.  I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Failed to launch testhost with error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. () ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.DesignMode.DesignModeClient.LaunchCustomHost(TestProcessStartInfo testProcessStartInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.DesignMode.DesignModeTestHostLauncher.LaunchTestHost(TestProcessStartInfo defaultTestHostStartInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.LaunchHost(TestProcessStartInfo testHostStartInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.<>c__DisplayClass37_0.<LaunchTestHostAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.<LaunchTestHostAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.DesignMode.DesignModeClient.LaunchCustomHost(TestProcessStartInfo testProcessStartInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.DesignMode.DesignModeTestHostLauncher.LaunchTestHost(TestProcessStartInfo defaultTestHostStartInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.LaunchHost(TestProcessStartInfo testHostStartInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.<>c__DisplayClass37_0.<LaunchTestHostAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.<LaunchTestHostAsync>d__37.MoveNext()<---

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler)
 Summary: Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Ignored: 0
Duration: 4.82 seconds
```

I can however run the test, but I need to **step DEBUG** through my tests.

Comment: Making your cry for help scream out in bold letters might have a different effect than you think. Otherwise, welcome to SO!

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know about 15.6.0 bugs.

Comment: @elgonzo Thank-you!

Comment: Possibly related: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/174688/issues-with-unit-test-framework.html

Comment: It is mentioned above to disconnect from VPN. For me it is opposite. Debug works only when **connected**.

Answer (score 3):

If you are use a **VPN connection**, first disconnect VPN,then close VS2017 and reopen

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VS2017, update your projects to use netcore 2.0 and it will work.

Had the same problem after installing VS2017 and trying to debug projects that I had created with netcore 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue every so often on a new Install with Windows 10. Usually after adding/removing other Tests/methods in my unit test class.

This is with VS `15.9.5` and ASP.Net Core `2.2`.

Restarting Visual Studio fixes it until the next time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

**reopen VS2017** or **stop Live Unit Testing** would work!

btw, I'm using .NET.Core2.1 webApi project.

Answer (score 0):

Run VS as Administrator, fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me Issue resolved with clearing the cache in

C:\Users\mdasari\AppData\Local\NuGet,
C:\Users\mdasari.nuget

Clean the solution and then Run the test cases